# Why i receive Error code 53011 in Azure to some access?

Tags: azure, security

I have a problem with my tenant because some users can not access their account because "User blocked due to risk on home tenant" with code error 53011.

We used conditional access and the policy to check the user risk.

The problem is that when I received the error, the user isn't at risk.

Do you have any solution?

Regards,
Domenico

Comment: Are those users guests? The error seems to be saying that the Conditional Access/other feature has blocked them in their _home tenant_.